# RAW exports wrong (Photivo, Rawtherapee)

Tags: image-processing, photo, image-viewers, photo-editing

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.
I started shooting my images in RAW (NEF) and downloaded Photivo to process them.
While working in Photivo, everything is OK. The problem is when you save the rendered image. Rendered preview in Photivo looks great, but the saved image is a little flatter, seems noisier, looks heavily compressed ( like dark areas of photos on Facebook ) and what was blue in the preview is purple in the saved result. Generally, preview looks good, result is ugly.
Setting higher JPG quality did not change anything visibly and neither did switching to .PNG (except 10x the filesize, of course)

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

UPDATE:
Tried Rawtherapee , there is a similar problem. Purple tint on blue tones, awful noise.
I have no idea where the problem could be. The previews look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not actually export wrong, it exports OK. You can see that when you open the exported image in Web browser or Shotwell or GIMP or whatever. As far as I know, only the "Image viewer" has this display problem. No idea why.

Comment: i don't believe i wasted so much time on this lol